# selecting subsets from matrix in steps of 14 in R and save it in a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

i have a matrix containing 14000 columns and 15 rows (matrixA)

i want to be able to select subsets of that matrix and put it a new matrix
and then save this matrix in a new list (containing all the subsets)

so for example i want to select the first the data with the first 14 columns and then for the next matrix i want to select the next 14.

it should be something like this:

```
matrixA[,1:14]
matrixA[,15:28]
matrixA[,29:42]
```

and so on...

in stead of typing this 1000 times i want to know if theres a function in R to select data in steps of 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
   lapply(seq(1,14000,by=14),function(x) myMatrix[,x:(x+13)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other options include:

```
 dim(matrixA) <- c(15,14,1000) #convert matrix to `array` and convert back to `list` using

 lapply(seq(dim(matrixA)[3]), function(i) matrixA[,,i])
```

or

```
 library(plyr)
 alply(matrixA,3)
```

Or

```
 lapply(split(1:14000, ((1:14000)-1)%/%14 +1), function(i) matrixA[,i])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
matrixA <- matrix(sample(1:200, 15*14000, replace=TRUE), nrow=15)
```